# How To go fully IPv6 with Cloud Flare, a web server with both ipv4 and ipv6?

Tags: networking, nginx, http, ipv6, cloudflare

I have setup an Nginx server in a machine which have both ipv4 and ipv6 addresses. Currently, its connected to CloudFlare and only use ipv4. I have 1 ipv4 address assigned to the web server.

Now what I want is, to become fully ipv6. Then connect to CloudFlare. So, if an ipv4 user comes to the site, CloudFlare will make sure that he can visit my ipv6 only site! Does it happen like that?

What is the best way to implement ipv6 on my server? Only ipv6 or both versions? How to implement it (In CloudFlare dns and in Nginx configuration file). Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFlare have an [Automatic IPv6 Gateway](http://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-cloudflares-automatic-ipv6-gatewa) feature which looks like it will proxy between IPv4 and IPv6 in both directions. You could use this to run your server on only IPv4 or only IPv6, but still provide both IPv4 and IPv6 access to users.

Answer (score 1):

As CloudFlare support just told me, they don't support ipv6 only hosts at the moment.

I hope they fix that soon!

Answer (score 0):

Use both ipv4 and ipv6, as this answer: [Should I use IPv6 only or both IPv4 and IPv6 in my web server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/421445/should-i-use-ipv6-only-or-both-ipv4-and-ipv6-in-my-web-server)

points out. Your hosting company should assign you an ipv6 address or a couple (million). You should give us your OS to find out what is the best way to set that up for your specific OS. CentOS is different than Debian for getting ipv6 on your server.

And no, I do not believe Cloudflare works like that. If you give it an ipv6 address, people on ipv4 who cannot connect to ipv6 will not be able to connect.